# What is the shortest code in java for accepting 2 binary numbers and returning their sum?

Tags: java, binary

I need to add two binary numbers and return the sum. No base conversions are allowed. I know the long method, using arrays. But is there anything shorter ? And by shorter I mean "having smaller code length". Thanks in advance.

In case I was not explicit enough, here is an example:

Input:

1101

11

Output: 10000

Comment: Do show us what you've tried and do tell us why you care about "having smaller code length".

Comment: Two binary numbers?  `int sum(int a, int b) { return a + b; }`  (It contains some unnecessary blanks, but you can figure that out.)

Comment: Keep in mind that all numbers in computers are binary.  How we think about them differs greatly, as we apply the meaning to the arrangement of bits.  So, you need to communicate more information about how you are representing your data.  `int a = 5;` is just as binary as `String a = "0101101101";`.  The solution differs greatly depending on the input.

Comment: @NPE What I did was very basic. I accepted the two numbers as strings and then using a loop added them digit-wise using sum and carry.

Comment: @HotLicks That didn't work. Maybe I'm not being to express what I want. Editted the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum of two (binary) integers `a` and `b` can be computed as `a+b`, because all arithmetic is done in binary.

If your input is in human readable strings rather than binary, you can compute their sum in binary using the standard [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) class:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

String sum(String a, String b) {
    return new BigInteger(a, 2).add(new BigInteger(b, 2)).toString(2);
}
```

Comment: Yes, "Human readable strings". That was what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Represent the binary numbers as two strings. Reverse the two strings. Then, you can iterate along both strings simultaneously, adding values to three arrays, two which represent the binary digit being added from the strings and the third to represent the carry digit. Create a fourth array representing the answer (you might have to find the limit for how long the answer can possibly be).

fill the answer array by using standard binary adding:

```
0 + 0 = 0 in the same position, 
1 + 0 = 0 + 1 = 1 in the same position, 
1 + 1 = 0 in the same position, and carry a 1 to the next position, 
1 + 1 + 1 = 1 in the same position, and carry a 1 to the next position.
```

Reverse the array and you'll have the answer as a binary number.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple options, not using any utility methods provided by Java. These don't account for sign (leading +/-) so they only handle whole numbers.

This first method converts the binary strings to integers, adds the integers, then converts the result back to binary. It uses a method-local inner class `Convert` to avoid duplicating the `binaryToInt()` code for each of the parameters.

```
    static String binaryAdd1(String binary1, String binary2) {
        class Convert {
            int binaryToInt(String binary) {
                int result = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < binary.length(); i++) {
                    char c = binary.charAt(i);
                    result *= 2;
                    if (c == '1') {
                        result++;
                    } else if (c != '0') {
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException(binary);
                    }
                }
                return result;
            }
        }
        final Convert convert = new Convert();
        int int1 = convert.binaryToInt(binary1);
        int int2 = convert.binaryToInt(binary2);

        String result = "";
        int temp = int1 + int2;
        do {
            result = ((temp & 1) == 1 ? '1' : '0') + result;
            temp >>= 1;
        } while (temp > 0);
        return result;
    }
```

This second method uses binary addition logic, as specified by JHaps in his answer, to directly add together the two parameters. No intermediate conversion to integers here.

```
    static String binaryAdd2(String binary1, String binary2) {
        final String validDigits = "01";
        String binarySum = "";

        // pad the binary strings with one more significant digit for carrying
        String bin1 = '0' + binary1;
        String bin2 = '0' + binary2;

        // add them together starting from least significant digit
        int index1 = bin1.length() - 1;
        int index2 = bin2.length() - 1;
        boolean carry = false;
        while (index1 >= 0 || index2 >= 0) {
            char char1 = bin1.charAt(index1 >= 0 ? index1 : 0);
            char char2 = bin2.charAt(index2 >= 0 ? index2 : 0);
            if (validDigits.indexOf(char1) < 0)
                throw new NumberFormatException(binary1);
            if (validDigits.indexOf(char2) < 0)
                throw new NumberFormatException(binary2);
            if (char1 == char2) {
                binarySum = (carry ? '1' : '0') + binarySum;
                carry = char1 == '1';
            } else {
                binarySum = (carry ? '0' : '1') + binarySum;
            }
            index1--;
            index2--;
        }
        if (binarySum.length() > 1 && binarySum.charAt(0) == '0') {
            binarySum = binarySum.substring(1);
        }
        String result = binarySum.toString();
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: The first method is not allowed as you have converted from binary to integer. The second one was what I did. I would like to know if there is anything shorter than this. Thanks.